# Trying to understand the members of this edge set

Tags: graph-theory

Let $A_1, ..., A_5$ be the sets $$A_1 = \{1, 2\}, A_2 = \{2, 3\}, A_3 = \{3, 4\}, A_4 = \{4, 5\}, A_5 = \{1, 5\}.$$

Vertex set V = $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ & edge set is...

$$E = \{\{i, j\} : i, j ∈ V, A_i ∩ A_j = ∅\}.$$

I'm trying to explicitly describe edge set E in plain English; but, the condition of $A_i ∩ A_j = ∅$ is tripping me up & I'm not sure what to include.

My guess is that if you have (for example)...$\{i, j\} = \{1, 2\}$; this means $A_1 ∩ A_2$ should equal ∅. In this case; $A_1 ∩ A_2 = \{2\}$ and so $\{1, 2\}$ can't be a valid member of the set.

Comment: [Here's a tutorial in MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Your guess is good. By the same token, $\{1, 3\}$ _is_ a member of the edge set.

Answer (score 3):

Your question will give a much more beautiful answer when setting $V=\{0,...,4\}=\Bbb Z_5$ instead of $\{1,...,5\}$. Then $A_i = \{i,i+1\}$ for $i\in V$.

Note that $A_i\cap A_j=\varnothing$ if and only if $i\not\in\{j-1,j,j+1\}$. So the edge set can be written as

$$E=\{\{i,j\}\mid i\not\in\{j-1,j,j+1\}\}.$$

Assuming a loop $\{i,i\}$ is not allowed anyway, we have that all possible edges are from $\mathcal E_V={V\choose 2}=\{\{i,j\}\mid i,j\in V, i\not=j\}$, hence

$$E=\{\{i,j\}\in \mathcal E_V\mid i\not\in\{j-1,j+1\}\}.$$

This is exactly the complementary set of edges to

$$E=\{\{i,j\}\in \mathcal E_V\mid i\in\{j-1,j+1\}\}=\{\{i,i+1\}\mid i\in V\}$$

which is the edge set of a $5$-cycle. So your graph is the complementary graph to $C_5$. As it is the case, the complement of $C_5$ is $C_5$ itself, see here

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Let's discuss describing edge set $E$ "in plain English," as you commented. Maybe drawing a picture will help.

[image]

- We can think of each vertex as a vertex on a pentagon, and can think of each set as the edges between these vertices.
- Each set $A_1, \dots, A_5$ holds a *pair* of vertices from $V$.
- The index $i$ has a special meaning, in that the set $A_i$ contains the number $i$ and the "next" number. For $A_5$, the "next" number after $5$ is $1$.
- Your guess is right: for example, $\{1,2\}$ cannot be in $E$ because $A_1 \cap A_2 = 2$, and we can see this in the diagram. $A_1$ and $A_2$ meet at $2$.
- So the set $E$ is represented by all the "criss-crosses" across the pentagon that do not follow the border of the pentagon (in red below). For example, the set $\{1,3\} \in E$.

[image]

In sum, $E$ corresponds to pairs of indices of sets that do not overlap.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to see that

$E=\{(1,3),(3,1),(1,4),(4,1),(2,4),(4,2),(2,5),(5,2),(3,5),(5,3)\}$

Comment: Note that for OP the graph is undirected, hence the edges are no *ordered* pairs, but two-element-sets.